# How to add a "title" to a name field in Awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I work in the printing/mailing industry and often find it necessary to merge titles or salutations into the name field of a mailing list. Given the following file format:

```
**SEQ_NO**    | **NAME**  | **COMPANY**        | **so on**  
:------------ | :-------- | :----------------- | :---------------  
1             | name1     | company1           | blahblah        |  
2             | name2     | company2           | blaseblah       |
```

What I am intending to do is to add ", DC" to the end of each name, resulting in name1, DC
name2, DC

I have gotten as close as I can find with help from another question on this site using the following in Awk (pipe delimited file input and output):

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS='|' '{$2 = $2 ", DC" }1' [input file] > [output file]
```

However, this adds the appended text to the header row also which I would prefer to avoid. Sure it doesn't take long to manually edit on one line, but ideally would like to incorporate above script into existing Perl scripts and would like to know of a way to achieve the results I did above, except not have to remove the ", DC" from the column 2 header.

P.S. sorry for formatting issues, new to posting here.

Comment: show how should look the final result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `NR > 2` condition to your code.  This means that it will only take effect for line number 2 and above.

```
$ gawk -F'|' -vOFS='|' 'NR > 2 {$2 = $2", DC" }1' data.txt
SEQ_NO | NAME | COMPANY | so on
:------------ | :-------- | :----------------- | :---------------
1 | name1 , DC| company1 | blahblah |
2 | name2 , DC| company2 | blaseblah |
```

Comment: This works quite well... after changing "NR > 2" to "NR > 1", and certainly the quickest considering. I will try the other method as well when I get some additional free time, thanks @EwanMellor

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat file.txt
**SEQ_NO**    | **NAME**  | **COMPANY**        | **so on**
:------------ | :-------- | :----------------- | :---------------
1             | name1     | company1           | blahblah        |
2             | name2     | company2           | blaseblah       |
$
$
$ cat filter.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
{
 if($1 ~ /[[:digit:]]/)
 {
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+ /,", DC ",$2); print
 }
 else
 {
  print $0
 }
}

$ awk -f filter.awk file.txt
**SEQ_NO**    | **NAME**  | **COMPANY**        | **so on**
:------------ | :-------- | :----------------- | :---------------
1             | name1, DC | company1           | blahblah        |
2             | name2, DC | company2           | blaseblah       |
```

Explained -

```
$1 ~ /[[:digit:]]/               : Looking for numeric field in column 1 i.e., SEQ_NO.
gsub(/[[:space:]]+ /,", DC ",$2) : Searhing for multiple space in column 2 and replacing them with ", DC".
```

Comment: It appears there is something missing at the end of your code @VIPIN_KUMAR. Fairly new to Awk so not sure, but running against data did nothing.

Comment: @OhmEye - I have changed awk one liner with awk script, check my updated Answer.